# Microsoft Office Data Connection to utilise an external XML Data source?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, xml, msxml-6, msxml

I want to be able to process or product for connecting an external XML data connector to Microsoft Office Products (specifically Excel) so that it's seamless to the product. Essentially the spreadsheet should act as if it's running an SQL query and update each time that you open the file.

What would be the best way for doing this?

Edit (further information):

Worth noting: Mapped XML Data sources cannot be used in pivot tables. However I would like to use the external xml data source to create pivot tables as well, if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Excel `Get External data` and specify an XML data source.  The data can be set to refresh on a variety of triggers including on file open.  Once the data is in Excel, it can be used as the source of a pivot table.

Note I have done some *very* basic testing done on Excel 2010 to confirm these claims. I think 2007 should work in a similar manner

Comment: This is essentially how I would do it also.

Comment: Appreciated - will look into this further and see how I go